# Mono for Android not appearing in AddIns Manager in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: xamarin.android

I have installed Mono for Android for Visual Studio 2010 Professional, but it does not appear in the addins manager.

(I followed the instructions in http://mono-android.net/Installation/Visual_Studio)

What am I missing?

Thanks,
Ben

BTW The Mono for Android MSI is build 1.0.1.10323

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't get listed in the Add-In Manager in Visual Studio. If you go to the Extension Manager, you should see an entry for "MonoDroid for Visual Studio" if it is installed correctly.